# Can I use form tag between 2 different CGI servers?

Tags: forms, cgi

I have two CGI servers running. One one windows and one on Ubuntu. Now I need to go from page of one server to page of another server and pass some information using method 'post'. And the files(under cgi-bin/) of both server are executable. I tried to use 
However, this does not work.
So my question is: Can I do this even when the file from another server is executable?

I know I can do a hyperlink but this only allows method='get' if I don't understand incorrectly.

Any inputs is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try to use?

Comment: I think I understand why I am wrong now. I try to use the path in my system but if I use the URL of the file on internet. It is dumb...

Comment: no worries, it's ok.